# WP_Query with Pagination and orderby meta_value_num showing duplicates

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, pagination

I have the following set of Arguments I'm running in a WP_Query.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
$args = array(
        'tag' => $taxonomy,
        'post_type' => 'initiative',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'category_name' => $category,
        'tag__not_in' => 15,
        'meta_key' => 'initative_weight',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      );
```

As this is, it works fine but when I page through the results, I see a handful of Duplicate content. Now, if I get rid of the pagination and just show everything, no duplicates.

```
$args = array(
            'tag' => $taxonomy,
            'post_type' => 'initiative',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category_name' => $category,
            'tag__not_in' => 15,
            'meta_key' => 'initative_weight',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
          );
```

Also, if I keep the pagination, but remove the orderby, the pagination exists and no duplicates.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
    $args = array(
            'tag' => $taxonomy,
            'post_type' => 'initiative',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'category_name' => $category,
            'tag__not_in' => 15,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
          );
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? I seem unable to run a WP_Query with Pagination & sorting by a custom field without getting duplicates. Yet, I can do each on it's own just fine. Am I missing a step or did I come across a bug?

Comment: I think your issue must be with using `tag` and `tag__not_in` at the same time.

Comment: Please show the code for your pagination and your loop in an [edit]. Could easily be that you override the main query, at least that would be my assumption when I read "works fine without pagination".

Comment: note that `tag__not_in` must be an array.

Comment: @Milo Yep, that was the issue. I put it in an array and it works. Strangely the order isn't the same (it is sorting correctly, but the values are 1-5 and most are set to 3. The ones set to 3 are different depending on if there is pagination.) Either way, that fixed it. If you want to submit and answer I'll gladly mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'tag' => $taxonomy,
    'post_type' => 'initiative',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'category_name' => $category,
    'tag__not_in' => array(15),
    'meta_key' => 'initative_weight',
    'orderby' => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC'),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
```

I changed tag__not_in to an array and updated the orderby to be an array as well.